# How to eliminate duplicates made by recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte, duplication, recursive, data-versioning

I have following schema in PostgreSQL 12 (objects and their relations are versioned by date ranges):

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_deps (
    id bigint,
    code text,
    name text,
    start_date date,
    end_date date
);

CREATE TABLE tmp_dep_parents (
    department_id bigint,
    parent_id bigint,
    start_date date,
    end_date date
);

INSERT INTO tmp_deps (id, code, name, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
    (1, '11111111', 'Root Dep', '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (2, '11111112', 'Sub Root Dep', '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (3, '11111113', 'Dep 1', '1970-01-01', '2021-02-23'),
    (3, '11111113', 'Dep 1', '2021-02-24', '9999-12-31'),
    (4, '11111114', 'Dep 2', '1970-01-01', '2020-01-01'),
    (4, '11111114', 'Dep 2', '2020-01-02', '9999-12-31'),
    (5, '11111115', 'Sub Dep 1', '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (6, '11111116', 'Sub Dep 2', '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31');

INSERT INTO tmp_dep_parents (department_id, parent_id, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
    (2, 1, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (3, 2, '1970-01-01', '2005-12-31'),
    (3, 1, '2006-01-01', '2006-12-31'),
    (3, 2, '2007-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (4, 2, '1970-01-01', '2010-05-01'),
    (4, 3, '2010-05-02', '2010-05-03'),
    (4, 2, '2010-05-04', '9999-12-31'),
    (5, 3, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
    (6, 4, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31');
```

> objects and their relations are versioned by date ranges

It means that object with id=1 can be named as "Root Department" from 1 Jan 2000 to 31 Dec 2021, and can be named as "Super Department" from 1 Jan 2022 to 31 Dec 9999.

Object with id=3 can  belong to object with id=2 from 1 Jan 1970 to 15 May 2003 and can belong to object with id=1 from 16 May 2003 to 31 Dec 9999

---

The hierarchy of objects can be changed at any time.
I am using recursive CTE to create MATERIALIZED VIEW and I noticed duplicates when I filter objects and their relations by date. And also I need an ability to view historical data too that is the reason why I can't just filter objects and their relations by date inside CTE.
My CTE is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE deps AS (
    SELECT
        dep.id,
        dep.start_date as dep_start_date,
        dep.end_date as dep_end_date,
        dep.name,
        dep.code,
        1::int AS "depth",

        dep.parent_id,
        dep.dep_par_start_date,
        dep.dep_par_end_date

    FROM all_deps dep

    WHERE dep.code = '11111111'

    UNION

    SELECT
        dep.id,
        dep.start_date as dep_start_date,
        dep.end_date as dep_end_date,
        dep.name,
        dep.code,
        s.depth + 1 AS "depth",

        dep.parent_id,
        dep.dep_par_start_date,
        dep.dep_par_end_date
    FROM all_deps dep
    INNER JOIN deps s ON dep.parent_id = s.id
),
all_deps AS (
    SELECT
        dep.*,

        dp.parent_id,
        dp.start_date AS dep_par_start_date,
        dp.end_date AS dep_par_end_date
    FROM tmp_deps dep
    LEFT JOIN tmp_dep_parents dp ON dp.department_id = dep.id
)
SELECT * FROM deps
```

The problem with duplicates occurs when I add the "depth" output in CTE.
And as I understand it correctly, the duplicates are hidden when I remove the "depth" output from CTE, but I can still get wrong data.
My CTE contains all versions of objects and their relations.
And I don't understand how to get the CTE to follow the correct hierarchy path.

---

I want to see the hierarchy of departments and the departments themselves as of 15 May 2020 or 9 June 2021 or any other date, that is why I put all data states (versions) to CTE.

Materialized view is created from RCTE:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW departments_mat_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE deps AS (
    SELECT
        dep.id,
        dep.start_date as dep_start_date,
        dep.end_date as dep_end_date,
        dep.name,
        dep.code,
        1::int AS "depth",

        dep.parent_id,
        dep.dep_par_start_date,
        dep.dep_par_end_date

    FROM all_deps dep

    WHERE dep.code = '11111111'

    UNION

    SELECT
        dep.id,
        dep.start_date as dep_start_date,
        dep.end_date as dep_end_date,
        dep.name,
        dep.code,
        s.depth + 1 AS "depth",

        dep.parent_id,
        dep.dep_par_start_date,
        dep.dep_par_end_date
    FROM all_deps dep
    INNER JOIN deps s ON dep.parent_id = s.id
),
all_deps AS (
    SELECT
        dep.*,

        dp.parent_id,
        dp.start_date AS dep_par_start_date,
        dp.end_date AS dep_par_end_date
    FROM tmp_deps dep
    LEFT JOIN tmp_dep_parents dp ON dp.department_id = dep.id
)
SELECT * FROM deps
```

And here is select from MATERIALIZED VIEW:

```
SELECT * 
FROM departments_mat_view
WHERE
    dep_start_date <= '2021-06-09'
    AND dep_end_date >= '2021-06-09'
    AND (dep_par_start_date IS NULL OR dep_par_start_date <= '2021-06-09')
    AND (dep_par_end_date IS NULL OR dep_par_end_date >= '2021-06-09')
```

Here is output from CTE:

```
"id"    "dep_start_date"    "dep_end_date"  "name"          "code"      "depth" "parent_id"     "dep_par_start_date"    "dep_par_end_date"
1       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Root Dep"      11111111    1       NULL            NULL                    NULL
2       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Root Dep"  11111112    2       1               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
3       "2021-02-24"        "9999-12-31"    "Dep 1"         11111113    3       2               "2007-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
4       "2020-01-02"        "9999-12-31"    "Dep 2"         11111114    3       2               "2010-05-04"            "9999-12-31"
5       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 1"     11111115    3       3               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
5       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 1"     11111115    4       3               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
6       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 2"     11111116    4       4               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
6       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 2"     11111116    5       4               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
```

Desired output is:

```
"id"    "dep_start_date"    "dep_end_date"  "name"          "code"      "depth" "parent_id"     "dep_par_start_date"    "dep_par_end_date"
1       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Root Dep"      11111111    1       NULL            NULL                    NULL
2       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Root Dep"  11111112    2       1               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
3       "2021-02-24"        "9999-12-31"    "Dep 1"         11111113    3       2               "2007-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
4       "2020-01-02"        "9999-12-31"    "Dep 2"         11111114    3       2               "2010-05-04"            "9999-12-31"
5       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 1"     11111115    4       3               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
6       "1970-01-01"        "9999-12-31"    "Sub Dep 2"     11111116    4       4               "1970-01-01"            "9999-12-31"
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue as follows (all code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=387e753a09ee3fb87164bf1ab4841b62)):

I added some records just to make sure that I was getting the dates I wanted - and in response the OP's comment about having a `cut_off` date...

```
INSERT INTO tmp_deps (id, code, name, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
(1, '11111111', 'Root Dep',     '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
(2, '11111112', 'Sub Root Dep', '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),

(3, '11111113', 'Dep 1',        '1970-01-01', '2010-02-23'),
(3, '11111113', 'Dep 1',        '2010-02-24', '2015-02-23'),
(3, '11111113', 'Dep 1',        '2015-02-24', '2019-02-23'),
(3, '11111113', 'Dep 1',        '2019-02-24', '2020-02-29'),
                                                            -- cut_off = 
                                                            -- 2020-01-01
(3, '11111113', 'Dep 1',        '2020-03-01', '9999-12-31'),


(4, '11111114', 'Dep 2',        '1970-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
(4, '11111114', 'Dep 2',        '2016-01-01', '2019-12-31'),
                                                            -- cut_off = 
                                                            -- 2020-01-01
(4, '11111114', 'Dep 2',        '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'),
(4, '11111114', 'Dep 2',        '2021-01-01', '9999-12-31'),


(5, '11111115', 'Sub Dep 1',    '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
(6, '11111116', 'Sub Dep 2',    '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31');

INSERT INTO tmp_dep_parents (department_id, parent_id, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
(2, 1, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),

(3, 2, '1970-01-01', '2005-12-31'), 
(3, 1, '2006-01-01', '2006-12-31'), 
(3, 2, '2007-01-01', '2014-12-31'),

(3, 2, '2015-01-01', '2020-12-31'),  -- one extra record before cut_off, 
(3, 2, '2021-01-01', '9999-12-31'),  -- and one after. You can experiment
                                     -- with changing the parent_id


(4, 2, '1970-01-01', '2010-05-01'), 
(4, 3, '2010-05-02', '2010-05-03'), 
(4, 2, '2010-05-04', '2015-12-31'),




(4, 2, '2016-05-02', '2021-05-03'), -- one extra record before cut_off, 
(4, 3, '2021-05-04', '9999-12-31'), -- and one after. You can experiment
                                    -- with changing the parent_id

(5, 3, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
(6, 4, '1970-01-01', '9999-12-31');
```

So, I established an arbitrary `cut_off` date of `2020-01-01`, so I made a CTE using it:

```
WITH d_cte (cut_off) AS
(
  SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE AS cut_off
)
```

and then picked out my records by chaining the CTEs as follows (example):

```
WITH d_cte (cut_off) AS
(
  SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE AS cut_off
)
SELECT
  t.id, t.code, t.name, 
  MAX(t.start_date) AS msd, MAX(t.end_date) AS med, 
  d.cut_off
FROM
  tmp_deps t, d_cte d 
WHERE start_date < d.cut_off
GROUP BY id, code, name, d.cut_off
ORDER BY code;
```

Result:

```
id  code    name              msd         med           cut_off
 1  11111111    Root Dep      1970-01-01  9999-12-31    2020-01-01
 2  11111112    Sub Root Dep  1970-01-01  9999-12-31    2020-01-01
 3  11111113    Dep 1         2019-02-24  2020-02-29    2020-01-01
 4  11111114    Dep 2         2016-01-01  2019-12-31    2020-01-01
 5  11111115    Sub Dep 1     1970-01-01  9999-12-31    2020-01-01
 6  11111116    Sub Dep 2     1970-01-01  9999-12-31    2020-01-01
6 rows
```

We don't even need to include the `cut_off` data in the selection (see fiddle) - just shown for clarity - can be removed for efficiency if required.

Using the `cut_off` date, I was able to apply the same logic to the `tmp_dep_parents` table as follows:

```
WITH d_cte (cut_off) AS
(
  SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE AS cut_off
)
SELECT department_id, parent_id, start_date, end_date 
FROM
(
  SELECT
    tdp.department_id, tdp.parent_id, tdp.start_date, tdp.end_date, d.cut_off,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tdp.department_id
                         ORDER BY tdp.start_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM tmp_dep_parents tdp, d_cte d
  WHERE tdp.start_date < d.cut_off
  ORDER BY department_id
) AS tab WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY department_id;
```

We use the `rn` = 1 to select the date of interest to us - will always be 1 because of `ORDER BY tdp.start_date DESC`...

Result:

```
department_id   parent_id   start_date  end_date
            2           1   1970-01-01  9999-12-31
            3           2   2015-01-01  2020-12-31
            4           2   2016-05-02  2021-05-03
            5           3   1970-01-01  9999-12-31
            6           4   1970-01-01  9999-12-31
```

I'm not using a RECURSIVE CTE (RCTE), so I can't get the depth directly, but I can do it by summing over this:

```
  CASE
    WHEN c2.parent_id = LAG(c2.parent_id) OVER () THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS cl
```

So, combining the three CTEs, and wrapping the `SUM()` of the `CASE` statement in a subquery, we get:

```
WITH d_cte (cut_off) AS
(
  SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE AS cut_off
),
cte1 AS
(

  SELECT
    t.id, t.code, t.name, 
    MAX(t.start_date) AS msd, MAX(t.end_date) AS med, 
    d.cut_off
  FROM
    tmp_deps t, d_cte d 
  WHERE start_date < d.cut_off
  GROUP BY id, code, name, d.cut_off
  ORDER BY code
),
cte2 AS 
(
  SELECT department_id, parent_id, start_date, end_date 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      tdp.department_id, tdp.parent_id, tdp.start_date, tdp.end_date, d.cut_off,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tdp.department_id
                           ORDER BY tdp.start_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM tmp_dep_parents tdp, d_cte d
    WHERE tdp.start_date < d.cut_off
    ORDER BY department_id
  ) AS tab WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY department_id
)
SELECT tab.*,  SUM(cl) OVER (ORDER BY parent_id NULLS FIRST) AS "The depth"
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c1.id, c1.code, c1.name, c1.msd, c1.med,
    c2.parent_id, -- COALESCE(c2.parent_id, 0) + 1 AS depth,
    c2.start_date, c2.end_date,
    
    CASE
      WHEN c2.parent_id = LAG(c2.parent_id) OVER () THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS cl
    
  FROM cte1 c1
  LEFT JOIN cte2 c2
    ON c1.id = c2.department_id
  ORDER BY c1.id, c2.department_id
) AS tab
ORDER BY tab.id, tab.parent_id;
```

Result:

```
id      code    name         msd        med        parent_id    start_date  end_date    cl  The depth
1   11111111    Root Dep     1970-01-01 9999-12-31 NULL        NULL   NULL             1    1
2   11111112    Sub Root Dep 1970-01-01 9999-12-31  1   1970-01-01  9999-12-31         1    2
3   11111113    Dep 1        2020-03-01 9999-12-31  2   2015-01-01  2020-12-31         1    3
4   11111114    Dep 2        2020-01-01 2020-12-31  2   2016-05-02  2021-05-03         0    3
5   11111115    Sub Dep 1    1970-01-01 9999-12-31  3   1970-01-01  9999-12-31         1    4
6   11111116    Sub Dep 2    1970-01-01 9999-12-31  4   1970-01-01  9999-12-31         1    5
6 rows
```

I believe that I have answered the question(s) as asked by the OP (twice - see edits). Check the link to the chatroom in the comments below for further requirements from the OP. I believe that this merits  a different question with further explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126314/discussion-between-dmitry-k-and-verace).